# Merge 2 data frame based on values on dataframe 1 and index and column from dataframe 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 DataFrame as follows

DataFrame 1
[image]

DataFrame 2

[image]

I wanted to merge these 2 DataFrames, based on the values of each row in DataFrame 2, matched with the combination of index and column in DataFrame 1.

So I want to append another column in DataFrame 2, name it "weight", and store the merged value there.
For example,

```
----------------------------------------------------
|         |  col1 | col2   | relationship | weight |
| 0       | Andy  | Claude | 0            | 1      |
| 1       | Andy  | Frida  | 20           | 1      |
```

and so on. How to do this?

Comment: please add data rather than screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `MultiIndex Series`:

```
df2 = df2.join(df1.stack().rename('weight'), on=['col1','col2'])
```